# How to do multiget in CQL3 for composite row key?

Tags: cassandra, cql3

CF schema:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
upperId int,
lowerId int,
hour timestamp,
counter text,
succ int,
fail int,
PRIMARY KEY ((upperId, lowerId), hour, counter));
```

each record is keyed by composite id upperId:lowerid, how can I do multiget with CQL3?

This is not valid:

```
select * from mytable where (upperid, lowerid) in ((10000, 1), (10000, 2), (20000, 1));
```

I can't do this either:

```
select * from mytable where (upperid = 10000 and lowerid in (1, 2)) or (upperid = 20000 and lowerid = 1);
```

I got error: missing EOF at ')'.

Please help point to effective way to do multiget for composite row key in CQL3.

Thanks,
William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQL does not yet support a logical "or" in select statements.

Instead, in your application your could combine the result sets from the two queries:

```
select * from mytable where upperid = 10000 and lowerid in (1, 2);
select * from mytable where upperid = 20000 and lowerid = 1;
```

Reference:

- SO question: [Alternative for OR condition after where clause in select statement Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139390/alternative-for-or-condition-after-where-clause-in-select-statement-cassandra)
- Latest [CQL docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_intro_c.html)

Comment: that comes surprising, OR is quite natural and standard relationship. any good reason preventing from supporting it?